# Сохранение фото в VK через execute

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Подскажите почему не сохраняет фото вот этот код:

```
return [API.photos.save({"album_id":242386440,"group_id":123885059,"server":637718,"photos_list":"[{"photo":"748167e711:y","sizes":[["s","637718897","3d17f","b-BX1sfsevI",60,75],["m","637718897","3d180","I0Ob3RY9hjo",104,130],["x","637718897","3d181","tjNMvSWyizQ",483,604],["y","637718897","3d182","JUdrMyKjuh0",533,666],["o","637718897","3d183","xWpDixiMEGU",130,163],["p","637718897","3d184","vK-LKl3A17o",200,250],["q","637718897","3d185","6IgMLLyJAYg",320,400],["r","637718897","3d186","c8zFZYKmOTM",510,637]],"kid":"9211a7fe51dc221ff6baa9c7f6a12ee8","debug":"xsymyxyyyoypyqyry"}]","hash":"9c01f547134f71446cfdb61fb7b400ac","latitude":0,"longitude":0,"caption":""})];
```

Выдает сообщение об ошибке:

> "error_code": 12,
> "error_msg": "Unable to compile code: '}' expected, 'photo' found in line 1"

Если параметр `photos_list` использую без кавычек, то выдает такое сообщение об ошибке :

> "execute_errors": [{
> "method": "photos.save",
> "error_code": 100,
> "error_msg": "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid"

Те же самые параметры, но только без метода `execute` — всё работает хорошо.
Но я хочу использовать `execute` потому, что мне нужно за раз сохранить несколько фоток.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `"photos_list":"[{"photo` — вас вот тут ничего не смущает? Вы знаете json?

Comment: как раз эта часть содержимое параметра photos_list приходит из вконтакте после загрузки картинки. Ткните пальцем что там не так?

Comment: То, что почитайте синтаксис json, кодирование строк в нём и экранирование спецсимволов :)

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, действительно значение в photos_list  нужно было экранировать все нужные символы))))

Answer (score 0):

Как уже ответили в комментариях: нужно было экранировать спец.символы. Решение будет выглядеть так:

```js
return [
    API.photos.save(
        {
            "album_id": 242386440,
            "group_id": 123885059,
            "server": 637718,
            "photos_list": "[{\"photo\":\"748167e711:y\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"637718897\",\"3d17f\",\"b-BX1sfsevI\",60,75],[\"m\",\"637718897\",\"3d180\",\"I0Ob3RY9hjo\",104,130],[\"x\",\"637718897\",\"3d181\",\"tjNMvSWyizQ\",483,604],[\"y\",\"637718897\",\"3d182\",\"JUdrMyKjuh0\",533,666],[\"o\",\"637718897\",\"3d183\",\"xWpDixiMEGU\",130,163],[\"p\",\"637718897\",\"3d184\",\"vK-LKl3A17o\",200,250],[\"q\",\"637718897\",\"3d185\",\"6IgMLLyJAYg\",320,400],[\"r\",\"637718897\",\"3d186\",\"c8zFZYKmOTM\",510,637]],\"kid\":\"9211a7fe51dc221ff6baa9c7f6a12ee8\",\"debug\":\"xsymyxyyyoypyqyry\"}]",
            "hash": "9c01f547134f71446cfdb61fb7b400ac",
            "latitude": 0,
            "longitude": 0,
            "caption": ""
        }
    )
];
```